LDAP test connection - Invalid DN Syntax
I am struggling trying to test my LDAP authentication using ldap.forumsys.com:389.
Server specifics here: Online LDAP Test Server
Here's the code I am using to communicate with server from my c# app:
using System.DirectoryServices;

string ldapServerAddress = "ldap.forumsys.com:389";
string ldapBaseDN = "DC=example,DC=com";
string ldapUserName = "CN=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com";
string ldapPassword = "password";

try
{
    using var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{ldapServerAddress}/{ldapBaseDN}", ldapUserName, ldapPassword);
    directoryEntry.RefreshCache();  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception caught: {ex.Message}");
}

Each time this code is run, it encounters "An invalid dn syntax has been specified." exception.
I've already tried a lot of different variations to connection parameters, like uppercase "DN" instad of lowercase, "read-only-admin@example.com" instead of "CN=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com" etc. Nothing seems to work though.
I am 100% sure the server works, I've connected to it via Apache Directory Studio and accessed its resources with no problem. I've also tried using DNs copied from ADS but that did not work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Correct me if I am wrong, but:
You’re using CN=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com as the DN for the user.
However, according to the forumsys LDAP test server documentation, the correct DN for the read-only-admin user should be uid=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com.

You may also bind to individual Users (uid)... Link

using System.DirectoryServices;

string ldapServerAddress = "ldap.forumsys.com:389";
string ldapBaseDN = "DC=example,DC=com";
string ldapUserName = "uid=read-only-admin,DC=example,DC=com"; // Changed from CN to uid
string ldapPassword = "password";

try
{
    using var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{ldapServerAddress}/{ldapBaseDN}", ldapUserName, ldapPassword);
    directoryEntry.RefreshCache();  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Exception caught: {ex.Message}");
}


Also:

Check the LDAP Path: Ensure that the LDAP path is correct. It should be in the format LDAP://hostname:port/DN. For example, LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com.

Use the Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN): Sometimes, using the fully qualified domain name of the LDAP server instead of its IP address can resolve the issue.

Check the DN: Make sure that the Distinguished Name (DN) is correct. The DN should be the path from the current entry back to the root of the directory. For example, uid=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com.

Enable Detailed Logging



No luck unfortunately, I've tested that, as well as binding to a specific user (uid=tesla for instance). Same result: "An invalid dn syntax has been specified."

I'm sorry to hear, I added some steps to my answer. Also double-check all your parameters to make sure they’re correct. Or you could try using the server address directly without the base DN.

However, I just found out the whole problem may be related to the utilization of DirectoryEntry with the test server. It's OpenLDAP and not AD. I managed to get data using LdapConnection class instead. I'll look more closely into it now and post an answer later.
